# Folders with . not being pulled into TeamCity (.well-known)

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, teamcity

I'm working on implementing deep linking with our website & app but I'm having some issues with Googles implementation of this. They require you to have the assetlinks.json file stored in a folder called .well-known. I believe the . is what is causing the issue.

Environment:

- Solution put together in Visual Studio 2015
- Code repo is Bitbucket
- TeamCity has build steps to use Octopack to then package up the site
  & deploy.

What I've already done:

- Double checked the files are included into the project.
- Double checked git.ignore to ensure files aren't set to be ignored.
- Run a local msbuild with octopack=true to generate the package; the files exist in this package.
- Checked on Bitbucket to check the files have been pushed to source control. They have.
  On TeamCity I have enforced a clean checkout. Still no files.

I appreciate that the problem may not be on TeamCity but I'm thinking its here that's giving me the issue so I'm hoping someone has come across this themselves and can point me in the right direction!!

Comment: Just to check: how did you verify .well-known isn't there? Cause if you did that for example on a linux box using ls it won't be listed as it's treated hidden..

Comment: I'm working in a Windows environment so I should be able to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed.

Team City was packing using the default version of NuGet, which for some reason was 2.X.

I targeted with version 4.X and it built without a problem.